# Max of 1d array after the ith element

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have written a code that find the local minima of an array as well as the local maxima. What I'm interested in is to find the global minimum and then find the global maxima between the global minima and the end of the array.

I first look for the first minimum, then the maximum following it, and so forth. So if we have 4 minima and 4 maxima, we have something like this -+-+-+-+ where - and + represent minima and maxima respectively. After this I get the global minimum, suppose it is the second one -+(-)+-+-+. Now I am trying to find the maximum between the last 3 maxima.

I tried the following where t integer, Mx (array of the location of the maxima), M ( array of the value of the maxima)

`t=maxloc(M,1,(t>1))`

For the case of global minimum at third

`t=maxloc(M,1,(t>2))`

Comment: Why would you need all these local minima/maxima, when you at the end only interested in 1 global minimum and 1 maximum of a part of the array? Cannot you do that directly, without diving into local extremum detection (which is not parameter-free)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I get what you are trying to do but what's wrong with a loop? There's no law everything has to be done in 1 statement

Comment: @AlexeyMints This is because in the case of an array the decay eventually ...the MIN functions will take the last point.

Comment: @IanBush Yea I will test that but I am trying to introduce as less variables as possible.